# Не слышен или неслышен?

Tags: частица-не

Как в ШКОЛЬНОЙ орфографии объясняется разное написание НЕ в следующих предложениях:

В саду замолкли птицы, не слышен листопад.

С берез, неслышен, невесом, слетает желтый лист.

Спасибо за ваши ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Орфографический словарь под редакцией Лопатина трактует так:  (недоступный слуху) и неслышный; кратк. форма *шен, шна* (очень тихий, бесшумный).

Comment: Существует прилагательное «неслышный»,  при этом можно заметить, что для  краткой формы встречается как слитное, так и раздельное написание НЕ,  как вы их различаете? Примеры:Ветер был слаб, неслышен, яхта шла тихо. Но, вероятно, мой голос был неслышен и неубедителен. 

Звук двигателя вплоть до высоких оборотов практически не слышен. Волны терлись о камни, и в их шуме не слышен был бег оленей по ночному берегу.

Comment: Вера, "не слышен" - предикатив. Неслышен - непосредственно указывает на признак.

Comment: Серж, предикатив - это слово категории состояния. Получается, что неслышен - это краткое прилагательное, а не слышен - краткое причастие или предикатив (сравнить: он не способен, голос не слышен). Так что это, как вы думаете?

Comment: Вера, предикатив, это не только слова категории состояния, это и именное сказуемое. Помните, здесь этот вопрос уже обсуждался?!

Comment: Неясное замечание.  Все предикативы  выполняют функцию  сказуемого, составляют его именную часть.  Обычно это безличное предложение, но краткие предикативные прилагательные являются сказуемым в двусоставных предложениях.

Comment: Я не говорю о том, что какие части речи выполняют роль предикатива, я говорю  о том, что СИС иначе называют предикативом. Я приводил ссылку.

Answer (score 4):

В первом случае сохраняется связь с порождающим глаголом "слышать" (отрицание выражается частицей, как и при отрицании действия глагола), здесь это способ сказать, что упомянутого источника звука говорящий не слышит (ему не слышно этого - возможно, этого и нет). Во втором случае листопаду приписывается свойство "неслышный" с оттенком поэтической вольности (по аналогии с более распространённым прилагательным "невесомый" в краткой форме).

Comment: Alex_ander, как вы думаете, школьники поймут ваши объяснения? И еще вопрос: если сравнить два очень похожих предложения: Не слышен листопад. -  Листопад тих, неслышен. Можно сказать, что позиция и наличие однородного прилагательного меняют  значение  формы "не слышен"? А грамматику? Мы в обоих случаях имеем дело с кратким прилагательным?

Comment: Возможно, младшим школьникам надо проще это растолковывать. А присутствие второго прилагательного, действительно, подводит к такому пониманию, убирая двусмысленность; позиция же, вероятно, просто сопутствует такому смыслу (в поэтическом тексте можно представить себе вариант отдельного "неслышим" в обеих позициях), но может послужить дополнительным ориентиром. В случае "не слышен" мне видится смысловой сдвиг слова в сторону причастия: прилагательным его не назвать, посколько оно выражает не свойство листопада, а ситуацию наблюдения (напр. не слышно по причине его отсутствия, окончания, и т.п.).

Comment: Тогда это краткое причастие или, может быть, предикатив?

Answer (score 2):

В школьной орфографии трактуется просто, как и в справочнике Розенталя:

В саду замолкли птицы, не слышен листопад.- Не с кратким прилагательным слышен (такой, что можно слышать, доступный слуху) пишется раздельно, потому что здесь отрицается доступность слуху.

С берез, неслышен, невесом, слетает желтый лист.-слитно, потому что утверждается качество НЕСЛЫШНЫЙ (тихий, бесшумный)

Подтверждает раздельность написания НЕ СЛЫШЕН синтаксическая роль - сказуемое, где общеотрицательное суждение выражается частицей НЕ, т.е. в нём есть отрицание, на прилагательные в роли определений это не распространяется.

Comment: Учащиеся также часто смешивают краткую форму прилагательного слышен (слышна, слышно, слышны), образованную от полной формы слышный, с кратким причастием услышан (услышана, услышано, услышаны), образованным от причастия услышанный.
Приходится поправлять, что здесь два кратких прилагательных-слышный(доступный слуху) и неслышный(бесшумный)

Comment: Я сомневаюсь в понятности такого ответа,  ведь можно сейчас же задать следующий вопрос: почему в одном случае отрицается доступность слуху, а во втором утверждается качество. Думаю, что здесь следует противопоставить краткое ПРЕДИКАТИВНОЕ прилагательное "не слышен" и обычное признаковое (качественное).  прилагательное  "неслышный/тихий" в краткой форме, при этом нужно найти в предложении признаки этих форм (наличие однородных членов, позицию краткой формы)

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо за ответы, они мне очень помогли прийти к следующему решению.

Сравним два варианта: (1) В саду замолкли птицы, не слышен листопад. - (2) Листопад  тих, неслышен.

В предложении (1)-  **краткое предикативное прилагательное**,  в предложении (2) - **краткое качественное прилагательное**.

**Краткие предикативные прилагательные** обозначают состояние, восприятие, в этом они сходны со словами категории состояния: **не слышно - не слышен**. По значению они  близки к причастиям, но у них форма прилагательного, а не причастия (слышный, слышен, Е - беглая гласная, а не суффикс ЕН).

**Противопоставление** "краткое предикативное прилагательное - качественное прилагательное" **следует отличать** от противопоставления двух прилагательных, например: **он небогат (беден) - он не богат (среднего достатка),** когда или отрицается признак, или утверждается противоположный признак.

Comment: Ну,Вера, Вы определённо совершили открытие, только краткие предикативные прилагательные уже изобретены до Вас, и это совсем не то. Предикативные имена прилагательные - это такие, которые   не употребляются в полной форме или не имеют соотносительных полных форм с тем же значением, обозначают внутреннее состояние, склонность, способность к какому-либо действию: властен ( "я не властен совершить это" властный -другое значение), волен, горазд, должен, намерен, обязан, рад, склонен, способен и др

Comment: А я не изобретала кратких предикативных прилагательных, я просто думаю, что "не слышен" входит в группу  кратких предикативных прилагательных, которые можно отнести к словам категории состояния. И нужно различать качественные и предикативные прилагательные, как мы различаем причастия и прилагательные (признак или действие/состояние).

Comment: Слышен - то же значение, что и слышный.(доступен слуху-доступный слуху).Не слышен листопад - листопад не доступен слуху, отрицается, что он доступен. Что тут непонятно, не понимаю. "почему в одном случае отрицается доступность слуху, а во втором утверждается качество?"- Ну, уж. придётся вдуматься в смысл.

Comment: В одном случае он тихий, незаметный,  а в другом случае наблюдатель не воспринимает его, у него состояние, недоступное для слуха.

Comment: Вот именно, разные значения, и Александр пытался ВАм сказать, что НЕ СЛЫШЕН сохраняет связь с глаголом, то. есть является сказуемым, ПРЕДИКАТИВОМ, а Вы развили его мысль до предикативного прилагательного, но это нарушение имеющейся  терминологии, это несколько разные вещи.

Comment: НЕ с предикативными прилагательными, действительно, ВСЕГДА пишется раздельно, но НЕ СЛЫШЕН к ним никак не относится.

Comment: Он не богат/небогат - здесь прилагательное тоже входит в состав СКАЗУЕМОГО,так что это не показатель. А вот Серж правильно оценил ситуацию: "не слышен - предикатив, неслышен - непосредственно указывает на признак". "Не слышен" является предикативом, потому что  обозначает возможность восприятия предмета и этим отличается от "неслышен", которое обозначает постоянный признак предмета.